# How can I copy each value and past it multiple times using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet1:
| A |
| B |
| C |

How can I copy values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 so I will get this?

| A |
| A |
| A |
| B |
| B |
| B |
| C |
| C |
| C |

...just copy each value from Sheet1 x times to Sheet2 using Excel VBA. I did find some solutions but too complex or too simple for my needs, like this one (I dont understand what "eRow" is):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
Worksheets("Sheet4").Rows(x).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
eRow = ActiveSheet.Cell(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(eRow)
Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I did find some solutions" Please show the solutions you found, and indicate the areas of those solutions which you do not understand / need adjusted for your needs.

Comment: I updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA would be helpful here, but I think your best bet is to do this with worksheet formulas. Using `INDIRECT()`, which allows you to change a string into a cell range, `CEILING()` which is like rounding up to the nearest integer, and `ROW()` to get the row number of the cell in which the formula resides, you could do:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & CEILING(ROW()/3,1))
```

Take that and copy it down `Sheet2` starting at `A1`

If you want it so it makes 4 copies of each cell from `Sheet1` then change that `3` to a `4` and you'll be set.